# SQL Server starts normally from Windows Services screen, but shows error through SQL Server Configuration Manager. Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, configuration, startup

I have a SQL Server 2005 instance that has worked fine for years. There have been no changes that I am aware of. Recently, I found that if I stop and then start the instance in SQL Server Configuration Manager, I get the error:

`The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details`

However, the service has indeed started, regardless of what the error says. If I dig through Event Viewer and the SQL Server ERRORLOG file, everything looks normal. There are no errors anywhere. In fact, if I start the service from the normal Windows Services screen (services.msc), it starts up immediately. Should I be concerned that it generates a false error through SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Also, is the Services section in SQL Server Configuration Manager just a "shell" of the full  Services screen, which is limited to SQL Server related services? Is there any reason not to stop and start SQL Server services from the full Windows Services screen?

Comment: I should also point out that when starting the SQL Server service from Configuration Manager, it takes about 25-30 seconds before I get the error (and it then starts anyway). And one in a while, it starts without the error. Using the Windows Service screen, the SQL Server service starts up within a second or two - every time.

Comment: I've found the same thing over the years.  Based on the fact that it only ever happens for me when it takes a while for the service to start up I believe (although I could be wrong) that it's just a timeout built into SSCM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Configuration Manager performs additional operations that the Windows Services does not. Please check [Technet SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) particularly if you have changed the service account and/or password recently or use startup options.

Comment: Thanks. I know that changing the service account/password should be done in Configuration Manager, but I still can't find what is generating the error, Nor can I find any reason a simple service start/stop should or should not be done via the Windows Services screen.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, is the Services section in SQL Server Configuration Manager just a "shell" of the full Services screen, which is limited to SQL Server related services?

Yes, SQL SCM is the SQLServerManager10.msc file that is opened as a snap-in Windows Management Console (mmc.exe).

> Is there any reason not to stop and start SQL Server services from the full Windows Services screen?

No, unless you want to configure something for a special one-time change or initial setup.

Here's more [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx).